# With the scope expansion, we now can ask non-beer questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, design

So we might need to remove the word "beer" from the question block:

[image]

Comment: I think that hint text is automatically tied to the site description or URL prefix or something like that.  This might thus be blocked by renaming, though if it's not it would be good to adjust.

Comment: @Marshmallow thanks; I hadn't noticed variations like that, but that clearly indicates it's possible!

Comment: I agree that this needs to be updated but we're in the midst of a transition. I'll see if we can make a change even though we don't have a new name site description, but it may have to wait until those are finalized.

Comment: No worries - I can still ask questions on whisky etc, though, right?

Comment: @RoryAlsop Yup, go for it!

Answer (score 4):

The new name is in place and we've updated the text in the "Ask Question" as well as on the Tour page.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a similar problem on the [Tour](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/tour) that needs addressing.**

---

[image: beer is yummy]

Comment: We're in the process of getting these changed.